# How to implement UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate in UIStoryboardSegue?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, uipresentationcontroller

This is what I do now:

```
func presentOverlayController(controller: UIViewController) {

    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
    controller.transitioningDelegate = self

    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

public func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    return OverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
}
```

It works pretty awesome. First I get the controller from storyboard using `.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`. Controller is presented the right way:

[image]

But the same result I need to achieve with my custom **segue**:

```
class OverlaySegue: UIStoryboardSegue, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    override func perform() {

        destinationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
        destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
    }

    //MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

    func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return OverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
    }
}
```

but it doesnt work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of `perform` you need to call `presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`.